# Package X requires unavailable shared library com.android.future.usb.accessory

Tags: android, android-emulator, usb, arduino

For some reason, I am getting the error `Package X requires unavailable shared library com.android.future.usb.accessory`.

This library is included under the project folder in Project Explorer.  [Project Folder] -> Google APIs [Android 2.3.3] -> usb.jar -> com.android.future.usb -> UsbAccessory.class, UsbManager.class.

I am using the Google APIs 2.3.3 (API 10).   I need it because I'm connecting it to an Arduino USB Host Shield.  I've been debugging on my phone up to this point, but now I need logs and debug info because my program isn't sending data for some reason, and I can't  figure out why.  The program will at least load and perform certain actions when I connect it to my computer (instead of using the AVD).  Using the emulator, nothing loads.

I am using an Android Virtual Device with Android 4.2.2 (API 17).

My manifest includes the following:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <uses library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"></uses-library>
      <activity android:name="ArduinoActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
      </activity>
    </application>
```

**Update:** I've changed my API to Android 3.1 (API 12).  I've changed the library to android.hardware.usb.accessory (instead of com.android.future.usb.accessory).  For some reason, I still get an error from the PackageManager (this time with the new library).  I've noticed it's pulling that library name from the manifest.  Any thoughts?  Still having the same issue!

**Solution to Update:** I forgot to change `<uses-library />` to `<uses-feature />`.  More documentation on Android vs Google APIs for USB & USB Accessories: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB Accessory mode does not work on API 2.3.3, only 2.3.4 and above. [Read here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#choosing)

Comment: Weird.  I wonder why it's included in 2.3.3.  Thanks for the catch.  I'll update when I get 3.0 installed and running.